# Freeze after waking up from suspend and entering password prompt, after updating to 21.04

Tags: suspend, lock-screen, gdm, 21.04

I recently updated to 21.04, suspend and wake up worked fine before.

After the update I noticed that after waking up from suspend and pressing enter to open the password prompt, the screen freezes. I am able to get into into a terminal and restart gdm but this kinda defeats the point of suspending.

I am not using Wayland and I am on the latest nvidia proprietary drivers, but I also tried it with noveau and I think this issue is unrelated to it as this does not seem to affect it.

The interesting thing is that the screen is not frozen after wake up immediately, *only after pressing enter to open the password prompt.* Before doing that I can open the accessibility and shutdown menu and move the mouse just fine. The lock screen also works fine when using it without suspending.

Logs don't contain anything interesting, but maybe I am looking at the wrong place.

Any idea what could cause this?

Comment: I'm also having this issue after upgrading to 21.04 w/ Nvidia, but it unfreezes after some time - sometimes seconds, sometimes closer to a minute or two.

Comment: I have not tried it for longer than a few seconds actually, I'll check if it's the same for me too

Comment: did it unfreeze for you at some point?
I have the same issues and tried all nvidia related fixes to the point that I am now only using the intel integrated graphics. Problem remains, but not every time.